# Is there any relation between the recursive neural network and recurrent neural network?

Tags: comparison, recurrent-neural-networks

Recurrent neural networks, abbreviated as RNNs, are widely used in deep learning literature, especially for text processing.

Are they related to recursive neural networks in any way?

I am asking for the general/special relationship that enables us to view the one in terms of another if possible.

Comment: The Wikipedia articles on the two types of network look like a good place for someone to start an answer.

Comment: @NeilSlater They seem to be different based on that, but at some places (like proofs) they are referring to the same...

Comment: Form the articles, recurrent are a sub-type of recursvive. I hope that someone who knows more about this can answer in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, recursive neural networks (recursive NN) are related to recurrent neural networks (RNNs), because they generalize the latter (at least, structurally), as stated in [section 10.6](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/rnn.html) of the Deep Learning book, similar to the way that a tree generalizes a list/array.

So, in a list/array, element $e_1$ is connected to element $e_2$, which is connected to element $e_3$, and so on. In a tree, element $e_1$ can be connected to more than one other element (node), and the same applies to the other elements, provided there are no cycles, otherwise, you get a graph, which is a generalization of a tree.

If these explanations weren't yet clear, the best way to understand the difference between the two is to look at the diagrams of an RNN and a recursive NN.

Here's an RNN.

[image]

The caption should describe the diagram (in case it is not clear). The important thing to note is that, on the left, we have an RNN, which looks like a list.

Here's a recursive NN.

[image]

which looks like a tree.

There are many variations of RNNs (e.g. Bidirectional RNNs, multi-layered RNNs, LSTMs, or GRUs) and recursive NNs (e.g. that attempt to have balanced trees, similar to the way that a Red-Black Tree is a balanced binary search tree), so we cannot give all the details about the differences between these two approaches.

However, a few things should be kept in mind

- recursive NNs might be used in the context of parse trees
- recursive NNs have been used to process data structures as input to neural nets
- nodes in recursive NNs don't necessarily perform a linear operation followed by a non-linearity